# How can I convert part of a filename to become the file extension?

Tags: windows, file, type-conversion, filenames, file-type

I downloaded a backup folder of about 3,000 files from our email service provider. None of the files have an associated filetype; instead the file extension was appended to the name of each individual file. For example:

- community-involvement-photo-1-jpg
- social-responsibility-31-2012-png
- report-02-12-15-pdf

I can manually change the last dash to a period and the files work just fine. I'm wondering if there is a way to batch convert all of the files so they can be sorted and organized properly. I know in the Command Line I can do something like `ren *. *.jpg` but there are several different file types contained in the folder, so it wouldn't work for all of them. Is there any way I can tell it to convert the last "-" in each file name into a "." ?

I'm on Windows 10; unable to install any filename conversion programs unless I want to go through weeks of trouble with the IT group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ordner = "c:\temp\pseudodaten"
$Liste  = (get-childitem -path $Ordner).Name

cd $ordner
foreach ($Datei in $Liste) { 
   $Length = $datei.length
   $NeuerName=$Datei.Substring(0,$Length-4)+"."+$datei.Substring($Length - 3, 3)
   rename-item -Path $Datei -NewName $NeuerName
}
```

Comment: Powershell-Skript bitte erst mal mit einem Ordner ausprobieren in dem paar Dateien liegen. Der Variablen dann den Pfad angeben. Schnipsel geht dann per cd in den Ordner, liest alle Dateien ein und zerpflückt den Namen.

Comment: First test this Powershell-Skript within an folder with some files. 
The Variable $Ordner needs this folder. Folder content will be read and filenames converted.

Comment: Flag my answer please ;)